# How to download picture in ios gallery with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, download, image

I have a problem. 
I would like to download pictures with phonegap cordova 2.1 and show them in the apple iphone/ipad galery.
I have tested this javascript function

```
$("#btnDL").click(function(){
    var file = $("#imgViewer img").attr('src');
    var aux =file.split('/');
    var fName = aux[aux.length - 1];

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    fileTransfer.download(encodeURI(file),"/var/mobile/Applications/9A25FA0A-49A9-4DED-BD83-5FF043A9075/Document/MyApplicationName",function(entry){
        alert("Image saved in "+entry.fullPath);
    },function(error){
        alert("ERR: "+JSON.stringify(error));
    });
});
```

The function tell me the file was saved in my iPad. But if I search in the gallery, there are any picture. I have thought to do a plugin in objective-C but I don't know enough this language. 
I have tested to do a plugins with this

http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/1097750723/phonegap-plugin-for-downloading-url

and this

https://github.com/aaronksaunders/FileDownLoadApp

but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finnaly I have resolve my problems with this plugin

https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin